# Как считать параметры командной строки в Qt? QCommandLineParser

Tags: qt, консоль

Приветстсвую! Возникла потребность считать параметры комнадной строки. Для этой цели я использую QCommandLineParser, а именно функцию `value`. Однако нужного результата добиться у меня не получается. Проблема в том, что функция возвращает пустую строку для обоих опций (`name_param`), (`port_param`). Ниже код функции main.
   #include "chatwidget.h"

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QCommandLineOption>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QCommandLineParser parser;
    QCommandLineOption name_param(QStringList({"n", "name"}));
    QCommandLineOption port_param(QStringList({"p", "port"}));
    parser.addOption(name_param);
    parser.addOption(port_param);
    parser.process(a);

    QString username, port;
    username = parser.value(name_param);
    port = parser.value(port_param);
    qDebug() << username << port;
    if (username.isEmpty())username = "User1";
    if (port.isEmpty())port = "2734";
//    qDebug() << username << port;

    ChatWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

А вот, что я ввожу в командную строку: `chat.exe -n name -p 2222`. Ожидаю получить `"name" "2222"`
В ответ получаю `"" ""`. Подскажите, что я делаю не так???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде создание опций неправильное

Как-то так:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCommandLineParser parser;
        QCommandLineOption name_param(QStringList()<<"n"<<"name","Name","default-name");
        QCommandLineOption port_param(QStringList()<<"p"<<"port","Port","default-port");
        parser.addOption(name_param);
        parser.addOption(port_param);
        parser.process(a);

        if(parser.isSet(name_param))
            qDebug()<<"name is " << parser.value(name_param);
        if(parser.isSet(port_param))
            qDebug()<<"port is " << parser.value(port_param);
```